# ForEach Loop not detecting any Controls (PictureBoxes)

Tags: c#, controls, picturebox

This following code is supposed to detect all PictureBoxes in the `Controls` property, and apply collisions to it. (This is in Windows Form for a CompSci final project). The problem is that it is not detecting any PictureBoxes; otherwise, the code runs. Any ideas?

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                if (x is PictureBox)
                {
                    if ((string)x.Tag == "platform")
                    {
                        if (PlayerPB.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                        {
                            force = 8;
                            PlayerPB.Top = x.Top - PlayerPB.Height;
                        }

                        x.BringToFront();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().Where(pb => (string)pb.Tag == "platform")`

Comment: Are the controls inside another container like a Panel or GroupBox? Is `IntersectsWith()` returning the correct results? Is the tag set properly?

Comment: Yes! They're inside of a panel.

Comment: `this` refers to the form. You're looking side the form's controls collection. This only has the top-level controls for the form. You need to look inside the Panel's controls collection instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recurse into each container within the main form and see if there are any PictureBoxes within there:

```
private void WirePBs(Control container) 
{
    foreach (Control x in container.Controls)
    {
        if (x is PictureBox) && (string)x.Tag == "platform")
        {
            if (PlayerPB.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
            {
                force = 8;
                PlayerPB.Top = x.Top - PlayerPB.Height;
            }
            x.BringToFront();
        }
        else if (x.HasChildren)
        {
             WirePBs(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call it by passing in the form itself:

```
WirePBs(this);
```